# How to avoid auto-started apps in Gnome 3 stealing focus

Tags: arch-linux, gnome

Is there any way to disable the focus-stealing behavior in GNOME whenever an app is launched? I have already tried changing the dconf value "focus-new-windows", but that doesn't make any difference, because I am not worried about apps that I launch from the terminal, but rather the auto-started programs (that take a minute or so to load at start-up and each time they steal the focus).

Comment: For me this is still an issue, how to solve this?

Comment: I "fixed" it by switching to XFCE. No more pain. Looks fantastic too if you get rid of the terrible default look

Answer (score -1):

You can select your startup application in **tweak tool** 
just install by following command:

$ **sudo add-apt-repository universe**

$ **sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool**

you should see a application called **tweaks** or you can run it by :

$ gnome-tweaks

then you can change or remove the application which auto-start on boot

Comment: yeah but that doesn't answer how I can make it such that it doesn't steal the focus. For example steam takes a minute to start, and during that time it will steal the focus 3 times, which is bothersome when you're typing